# Custom entity datetime field definition

Tags: 8, entities, datetime

I created an entity in a module, using code. I generated skeletons with `drupal console generate:entity:content` (without bundles), and then added a datetime field to my TestFieldEntityItem.php, in `baseFieldDefinitions()`.

```
$fields['test_date_incode'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Test date'))
  ->setDescription(t('Test.'))
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setSettings([
    'datetime_type' => 'date'
  ])
  ->setDefaultValue('')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
    'settings' => [
      'format_type' => 'medium',
    ],
    'weight' => 14,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'datetime',
    'weight' => 14,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

I can add data to my entity, without problem, but if I want to add another field (a simple text field) through the UI, I get this error:

> Un problème est survenu à la création du champ test_text : The "datetime" plugin does not exist.

(In English, the error message is *A problem occurred creating field test_text: The "datetime" plugin does not exist.*)

The field is created, but I don't like this error. It seems my code to create the datetime field is not the right one.
I use the Calendar module, if this could have any incidence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard to tell which plugin is missing. A guess would be it is a missing field widget plugin which causes the error when you try to add a new field to the default form mode. Then change the plugin name to something like this:

```
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
```

If this is not the error, then provide a full error message with a backtrace.

Comment: YOU. ARE. AMAZING.
I didn't understand what "Plugin" mean here, and I had no other error.
Thanks !