# Adding a base field definition in an update hook - it's not appearing

Tags: 8, entities, hooks, updating

I want to add another base field to a Drupal entity. It used to be possible to just change the code for the entity definition and then update it via the Drupal console. But now it has to be done in an update hook.

I've added the following update hook, done `drush updb` and the process completes without errors. I then did `drush cr` to clear the cache, and then opened up the edit form for the entity in question and gave it a hard refresh. But the new field has not appeared. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks. The code is based on this: https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742, section named "Installing a new field storage definition".

```
function opencase_entities_update_8002() {
  $storage_definition =  \Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
      ->setLabel(t('Date and time'))
      ->setDescription(t('When the activity started.'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setSettings([
        'datetime_type' => 'date'
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('2000-01-01')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'weight' => -3,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'weight' => -3,
      ]);

  \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()
    ->installFieldStorageDefinition('activity_date_time', 'oc_activity', 'oc_activity', $storage_definition);
}
```

Comment: Does you have [entity form modes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/display-modes-view-modes-and-form-modes) defined?  Might need to add this new field to them?

Comment: Thanks but no, not using them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your display options configuration (reference [4k4's answer to #244122](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/244123/82623)).

Try this:

```php
function opencase_entities_update_8002() {
  $storage_definition =  \Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
      ->setLabel(t('Date and time'))
      ->setDescription(t('When the activity started.'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setSettings([
        'datetime_type' => 'date'
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('2000-01-01')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'datetime_default',
        'settings' => [
          'format_type' => 'medium',
        ],
        'weight' => -3,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'datetime_default',
        'weight' => -3,
      ]);

  \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()
    ->installFieldStorageDefinition('activity_date_time', 'oc_activity', 'oc_activity', $storage_definition);
}
```

**Edit:** Don't forget to update your Entity definition as well!

Comment: would you mind to explain (update entity definition) ? I added new field to custom Entity using hook_update_N, but it didn't appear in UI.